# How to check if a question had ever hit HNQ

Tags: support, hot-questions

I am curious to know that is there a way to check whether a question has/had ever hit HNQ in the past (ever)?

Comment: ["When you google the exact question title then you can easily see..."](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303502/839601)

Comment: @gnat Same case for Bing too?

Comment: I think this trick should work with any search engine that properly indexes Stack Exchange pages

Comment: Usually insane amount of views means it was HNQ, especially in smaller sites which don't get lots of visitors. For example I'm pretty sure [this question](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21216/why-do-i-only-breathe-out-of-one-nostril) was HNQ, with catchy title and all.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd No guarante - I have seen questions like ones with 200 views and 3 votes in HNQs as well

Comment: Maybe in the beginning, but if a question sticks there for over a day, I really don't think it will have less than 1000 views.